# Creating a C# Amazon SQS Client in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

There is [some documentation](https://docs.servicestack.net/amazon-sqs-mq) on using Amazon SQS as an MQ Server forServiceStack [Messaging API](https://docs.servicestack.net/messaging)

But the message publisher is frontend web code and when you dig into the [Email Contacts demo](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/EmailContacts) app, it is using Rabbit MQ.

There is a ServiceStack [Email Contacts AWS App demo](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/AwsApps/tree/master/src/AwsApps/emailcontacts) but it doesn't use the Messaging API.

Trying to use the Rabbit MQ Integration Test in Email Contacts as an example:

```
[Test]
public void Can_Send_Email_via_MqClient()
{
    var mqFactory = new RabbitMqMessageFactory();

    using (var mqClient = mqFactory.CreateMessageQueueClient())
    {
        mqClient.Publish(new EmailContact { ContactId = 1, Subject = "UnitTest MQ Email #1", Body = "Body 1" });
        mqClient.Publish(new EmailContact { ContactId = 1, Subject = "UnitTest MQ Email #2", Body = "Body 2" });
    }
}
```

I quickly confused and lead astray and the ServiceStack API for Sqs seems very different than RabbitMQ. I cannot even seem to be able to use a strongly type POCO as a Message:

```
[Fact(DisplayName = "Tests that a successful message is published and received")]
public async void TestMessage()
{
    var mqFactory = new SqsConnectionFactory("awskey", "awssecret", RegionEndpoint.USWest1);

    using (IAmazonSQS mqClient = mqFactory.GetClient())
    {
        var req = new SendMessageRequest("query", "hello");

        await mqClient.SendMessageAsync(req);
        //mqClient.Publish(new Hello { Name = "World" });

        //var rec = new ReceiveMessageRequest();
        //await mqClient.Re

        //var responseMsg = mqClient.Get<HelloResponse>(QueueNames<HelloResponse>.In);
        //mqClient.Ack(responseMsg);
        //responseMsg.GetBody().Result //= Hello, World!
    }
}
```

Is there an example app using the ServiceStack Messaging API with SQS as the MQ Server?

Answer (score 2):

> There is a ServiceStack [Email Contacts AWS App demo](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/AwsApps/tree/master/src/AwsApps/emailcontacts) but it doesn't use the Messaging API.

Note AWS Apps does register the [AWS SqsMqServer](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/AwsApps/blob/2fef4967f24005f927548dc08d2f1978f08765ef/src/AwsApps/AppHost.cs#L89-L99):

```
//EmailContacts
ConfigureSqsMqServer(container);

//..

private void ConfigureSqsMqServer(Container container)
{
    container.Register<IMessageService>(c => new SqsMqServer(
        AwsConfig.AwsAccessKey, AwsConfig.AwsSecretKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1) {
        DisableBuffering = true,
    });

    var mqServer = container.Resolve<IMessageService>();
    mqServer.RegisterHandler<EmailContacts.EmailContact>(ExecuteMessage);
    mqServer.Start();
}
```

There's also a number of examples in [SqsMqServerTests.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Aws.Tests/Sqs/SqsMqServerTests.cs).

If you want to use [ServiceStack MQ's high-level APIs](http://docs.servicestack.net/messaging), you'd need to use ServiceStack's MQ classes instead of AWS's SQS classes directly.

Basically it works like every other MQ Server, you can fetch an MQ Client from the `IMessageFactory` or `IMessageService` (registered in your AppHost) and use it to publish DTOs:

```
var mqFactory = HostContext.TryResolve<IMessageFactory>(); //or
//var mqFactory = HostContext.TryResolve<IMessageService>().MessageFactory;

using (var mqClient = mqFactory.CreateMessageQueueClient())
{
    mqClient.Publish(new Hello { Name = "World" });
}
```

Although the preferred API within a ServiceStack Service is to use `PublishMessage()`:

```
PublishMessage(new Hello { Name = "World" });
```

> Note requests to the `/oneway` pre-defined endpoint are [automatically published to the registered MQ Server](https://docs.servicestack.net/messaging#oneway-http-requests-are-published-to-mq-then-executed).

In client Apps without a registered `SqsMqServer` you'd create a `SqsMqMessageFactory`:

```
var mqFactory = new SqsMqMessageFactory(new SqsQueueManager(...));
using (var mqClient = mqFactory.CreateMessageQueueClient())
{
    mqClient.Publish(new Hello { Name = "World" });
}
```

Comment: how do I define which Amazon SQS queue name to use, I have multiple SQS queues, 1 named "queue1" and another named "queue2"?

Comment: @BrianOgden ServiceStack MQ handles creation and naming of queues as per the [message workflow](http://docs.servicestack.net/messaging#message-workflow). Each different Request DTO / type of Queue needs its own Queue but there's some customizations possible from the static [QueueNames](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Messaging/QueueNames.cs) config class like `QueueNames.SetQueuePrefix("site1.")` if you want all your Queues for this App to start with a `site.` prefix. (any config needs to be set on both Server+Client & only once on Startup)